# Find shortest path using Boost Dijkstra with specified MAX DISTANCE

Tags: c++, boost, shortest-path, dijkstra

I love using boost's dijkstra implementation to find the shortest path from a node

However, in my current problem, I have a huge graph and only need to find shortest paths to nodes that are within a certain distance

I can implement this myself, but I believe boost's implementation is much more efficient than mine, so I prefer to use boost for the task

I just wonder if there is a way to tell boost's dijkstra to stop looking for shortest paths if nodes are too far -- as it will significantly speed up the algorithm in this case

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. Basically stopping the algorithm from the visitor should be possible. I am however concerned that the index will still be constructed sized to all vertices when only handful will ever be needed.

Comment: that is true, it's been a while and I decided to implement the dijkstra algorithm myself. It's much faster for my need

Comment: I would also be very interested if such feature existed...

Answer (score 2):

It is a very simple modification of the Dijkstra algorithm. While you iterate over outgoing edges from vertex v, just ignore each edge e, where `e.weight + v.dist > max`.